# How do I view favorited questions?

Tags: support

A fairly basic question I know, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to view past questions that I've marked as my favorites. I marked one earlier today hoping to look at it again later, and now I can't find it, and I have no idea how to look at questions I've marked thusly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's in your profile, right below your bio.

Answer (score 7):

You click on the favorites tab below your biography on your profile page.

[image: NovaSword's Profile]

Comment: Beat me to it! I took too long making my freehand circle. :(

Comment: Ack, I missed that entirely.  Thank you!